# Segmentation fault while returning integer between classes

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm working with a program having multiple classes. The three classes involved in this issue are `cWorld`, `cOrganism` and `cPopulation`.

I'm calling a function in `cOrganism` that has the following lines:

```
printf("Right before NewCluster\n");
int new_cluster_id = m_world->NewCluster();
printf("Right after NewCluster\n");
```

The function calls the `NewCluster()` function in `m_world` (an instance of class `cWorld`).

```
int cWorld::NewCluster()
{
  return GetPopulation().AddCluster();
}
```

Which in turn calls the function `AddCluster()` for whatever population exists in the world (an instance of `cPopulation`).

The `AddCluster()` function looks like this:

```
int cPopulation::AddCluster(){
  int new_id = 0;
  if(cluster_array.GetSize()!=0){
    cOrgCluster clus = cluster_array[cluster_array.GetSize()-1];
    int last_id = clus.GetID();
    new_id = last_id+1;
  }

  cOrgCluster cluster;

  cluster.Setup(m_world,new_id);

  cluster_array.Push(cluster);

  printf("Check if flow reaches here, cluster-id = %d\n",new_id);

  return new_id;
}
```

Interestingly, I get the following output from this:

```
 Right before NewCluster
 Check if flow reaches here, cluster-id = 0
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It seems that AddCluster() is working as expected but there is some issue returning the integer value of `new_id` back to the function in `cOrganism`. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I was previously returning the cluster object itself instead of its ID but was facing the same problem. Thinking it was something to do with returning the wrong pointer I changed it to ID instead. The problem still persists.

Comment: Probably memory corruption.  Try valgrind or electric fence to find the bug... what you're seeing is a delayed failure.

Comment: To expand on the above, the problem could be triggered by something the destructor of `cluster` does. It could be because there's a bug in the destructor or it could be because something has become corrupt that causes the perfectly good code in the destructor to fault. If you want to keep trying to narrow it down with `printf` statements, put some in that destructor. Though it could be memory corruption that's already happened.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz. Thanks! I was deleting a pointer owned by another class in the destructor. **Removing the delete statement fixed the problem!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've shown, it looks like the only thing that's happening when your code is crashing is that the destructor for `cluster` is running. So it's most likely either a bug in that destructor itself or some memory corruption has already happened and the destructor is tripping over it.

To continue troubleshooting using `printf`s, put some in the destructor for `cOrgCluster`. Alternatively, use a debugger such as `valgrind` to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: I was deleting a pointer owned by another class in the destructor. Removing the delete statement fixed the problem!